# Where clause operator precedence

Tags: sql, mariadb, where-clause, operator-precedence

Can anyone tell me the precedence of the following where clausule (using parentheses), Mariadb? I can't figure it out because of the multiple and's

```
WHERE
    (
        A = 1
    )

OR 
    (
        B = 2
    )

AND 
    (
        C = 3
    )

AND 
    (
        D = 4
    )
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`AND` goes before `OR`.

What you get is `WHERE A = 1 or (b = 2 and c = 3 and D = 4)`.

Is that what you want?